# Material Design <style> element placement

Tags: dart, dart-polymer, material-design

The placement of the  tag for material design seems to be different than for polymer-components.

Previously I used the following placement:

```dart
<polymer-element name='-form'> 

  <style>

  </style>  

  <template>



  </template>

  <script type="application/dart">

    import 'package:polymer/polymer.dart';
    import 'dart:html';

    import 'package:epimss_polymer/.dart';


    @CustomTag( '-form' )
    class Form extends PolymerElement
    {

      @observable 

      Form.created() : super.created();

    }

  </script> 
</polymer-element>
```

I am now investigating Google Material Design and found that the CSS placed within the |style| tags are not rendered.

Yet, if I place the tags within the |template| tags it works.

```dart
<polymer-element name='-form'> 

  <template>

    <style>

    </style>    

  </template>

  <script type="application/dart">

    import 'package:polymer/polymer.dart';
    import 'dart:html';

    import 'package:epimss_polymer/.dart';


    @CustomTag( '-form' )
    class Form extends PolymerElement
    {

      @observable 

      Form.created() : super.created();

    }

  </script> 
</polymer-element>
```

I note that the information at http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/styling.html

DOES use the last option.

What is correct for dart-polymer?

Comment: I m using Polymer with dart since November, and as far as i use it, i always had to put the style tag within the template tag to make it works... :$

Comment: @Vloz. Thanks. I must have being doing something incorrect and getting away with it.

Comment: Can you please add what style rules you put into the style tag. I doubt that it matters where you place an empty style tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The style tag for a Polymer element is always inside `<template>` tag. There must be something else that causes this behavior.

Have you tried to place the `-` dash in the middle of the name instead of the front?
Even when this might be valid, could be that nobody tried this before and doesn't work as expected.

Comment: The - was for illustration only. I use the template for quick copy and paste for a new component. I simply add a prefix to the form. All my readings suggest placing the style tags in the template. I will do that from now on. Thanks.

Comment: It could have been the content of the style tag that works differently depending on where it's placed. But to style a tag from the inside it definitely needs to be inside the `<template>` tag.